# How to POST NON-JSON request using Apache HttpAsyncClient?

Tags: java, json, apache-httpasyncclient

I am trying to use apache httpAysncClient post request where I am hitting an API with textfile(having plain text data) and in response i will get a string data.
How can I use apache httpAysncClient?

Comment: I want to use apache httpClient Asynchronously. In previous question it was synchronous.

Comment: Then your question is simply unclear as you don't describe what you've tried and why that isn't working for you.

Comment: That is working for me when I am using synchronous httpClient.
But can I use httpAysncClient as well for this?

Comment: What does your non-working httpAysncClient implementation look like, what happens when it runs, what do you expect should happen instead? Edit the question to contain all of that.